# Bridge PPTP VPN with local network

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, bridge, pptpd

I have configured on my Ubuntu a VPN server using PPTPD. I can connect to it from outside of my LAN, I can use it's internet connection. But I cannot see my LAN clients (because the VPN and the LAN are on different networks).

This is my configuration:
- PPTP VPN: 10.99.99.0/24, localip: 10.99.99.99
- LAN: 192.168.1.0/24

Is it possible somehow to create a bridge between my LAN and the PPTP VPN? So that I can access the clients from the LAN also. If so, how can I do that?
As I understood the PPTP VPN must be configured on a different network than the LAN.

Comment: PPTP is insecure. You should not use it.

Comment: @Mircea Vutcovici not even with TLS?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure PPTP VPN to use same subnet the LAN uses. I used it with such configuration. Or, you can add firewall rules to allow traffic between the two different subnets like following:

```
Src=192.168.4.0/24, Dst=192.168.1.0/24 srcport=ANY, dstport=ANY ALLOW
Src=192.168.1.0/24, Dst=192.168.4.0/24 srcport=ANY, dstport=ANY ALLOW
```

By the way, beware that PPTP is compromised protocol; consider PPTP as unencrypted protocol.